# How to execute a query in with .NET Google Drive API?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm using the C# API V2 for Google Drive and I can't seem to find the FilesResource.ListRequest.Fetch() method... I see that the FilesResource.ListRequest interface is slightly different from that described in the google drive documentation, so I guess that some changes have been done to it, but were not reflected in the web docs. Anybody knows how am I supposed to execute a query now?

This is what I'm trying to run:

```
public void SomeMethod(Settings settings)
{
    var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, settings.ApiKey, settings.ApiSecret);
    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, AuthProvider);
    _driveService = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer {Authenticator = auth});

    var request = _driveService.Files.List();
    request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";

    request.Fetch() // <-- This method does not exist! :/
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your code with the latest version of the library and it builds correctly. Are you using the latest version of the library?

`FilesResource.ListRequest` extends `Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.FileList>` which defines `Fetch()`:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Requests/ClientServiceRequest.cs#197

Answer (score 2):

Use the Execute() method instead of the Fetch()

```
request.Execute()
```

Comment: As of Feb 2014, the .Execute method also seems to have disappeared from FilesResource.ListRequest.  I can't find an alternative method to use.  Any clues?  Verified that I am using the latest Google.Apis and Google.Apis.Drive in NuGet in VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

The current method seems to be `ExecuteAsync`.

```
var request = _driveService.Files.List();
request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";

var result = await request.ExecuteAsync()
```

I'm not sure if that's only for Windows Store and Windows Phone 8.1 apps or if the `Execute` method has been removed everywhere.